# Проверка на переполнение массива

Tags: массивы, c++

Как можно подправить проверку на переполнение? Она не совсем корректна...

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

char* Rus(const char* text);

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL)); //делаем rand() зависящим от текущего времени, по сути аналог randomize()

    int n,i,k; //размер массива, сколько затем добавить
    int min, max; //минимальный и максимальные элементы
    int min_pos, max_pos; //их позиции
    cout << Rus( "Введите размер массива:") << endl;
    cin >> n; //считываем его
    int a[100]; //объявляем массив нужного размера

    cout << Rus("Массив имеет вид:") << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //заполняем массив случайными числами от 0 до 99 и печатаем
        a[i] = rand() % 100 - rand() % 100;
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << Rus("Удаляем из массива элементы с четными индексами:") << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) { //удаление нечетных индексов
        a[i] = a[i * 2 + 1];
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    n /= 2; //уменьшаем n, ведь удалили элементы
    cout << endl;

    cout << Rus("Сколько элементов добавить в конец массива:") << endl;
    cin >> k;
    if ((k > n && n) || (k > 1 && !n)) //проверка на переполнение
        cout << Rus("Нельзя добавить так много элементов!") << endl;
    else {
        for (int i = n; i < n+k; i++) { //добавляем еще случайных элементов в конец
            a[i] = rand() % 100 - rand() % 100;
        }
        n += k; //увеличиваем n, ведь якобы добавили элементы
        cout << Rus("Массив теперь имеет вид:") << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //печатаем наш новый массив
            cout << a[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    min = a[0], min_pos = 0;
    max = a[0], max_pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //ищем минимальный и максимальный элементы
        if (a[i] < min) {
            min = a[i];
            min_pos = i;
        }
        if (a[i] > max) {
            max = a[i];
            max_pos = i;
        }
    }
    cout << Rus( "Минимальный элемент текущего массива:") << endl;
    cout << min << endl;
    cout << Rus("Максимальный элемент текущего массива:") << endl;
    cout << max << endl;
    a[min_pos] = max; //меняем местами минимальный и максимальный
    a[max_pos] = min;
    cout << Rus("Массив после перестановки:") << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << Rus("Первый отрицательный элемент:") << endl;
    int j = 0;
    while (a[j] >= 0 && j < n) j++;
    if (a[j] >= 0) 
        cout << Rus("В массиве нет отрицательных элементов!");
    else {
        cout << a[j] << endl;
        cout << Rus("Количество сравнений для его поиска:") << endl;
        cout << j + 1 << endl;
    }

    cout << Rus("Массив, отсортированный включением:") << endl;
      int x;
      for(i=1; i<n;i++)
      {
      x=a[i];//запомнили  элемент, который будем вставлять
      j=i-1;
      while(x<a[j]&&j>=0)//поиск подходящего места
      {
         a[j+1]=a[j];//сдвиг вправо
         j--;
    }
    a[j+1]=x;//вставка элемента
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    } 
    cout << endl;
    cout << Rus("Первый отрицательный элемент:") << endl;
    if (a[0] >= 0) 
        cout << Rus("В массиве нет отрицательных элементов") << endl;
    else {
        cout << a[0] << endl;
        cout << Rus("Количество сравнений для его поиска:") << endl;
        cout << 1 << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
char bufRus[256];
char* Rus(const char* text)
{
CharToOem(text,bufRus);
return bufRus;
}
```

Comment: А в чем, собственно, тут заключается проверка на переполнение? А  вижу только проверку того, чтобы не было добавлено элементов больше, чем уже добавлено.

Comment: а как сделать проверку именно того, чтобы проверялось не превысили ли мы размер массива(в общем)?

Comment: Зависит от  того, как массив объявлен. Вы программу приведите и напишите, что при каких входных данных работает, а что нет. Главное пишите, что **видите** на экране.

Comment: вся программа приведена выше, работает все, только надо сделать проверку, чтобы узнать не превысили ли мы сам массив при добавлении к элементов в конец массива.А то у меня проверка проверяет не добавили ли мы больше элементов чем хотели, например задали добавить 2 элемента, а добавилось 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, наверное

```
int a[100];
...
if ( (k+n)>100) ) //
    cout << Rus("Нельзя добавить так много элементов!") << endl;
else {
```

Лучше объявить число 100 константой, чтобы не писать несколько раз